# How to solve a simple non-linear optimisation problem in order to find the minimum point in a hyperbola?

Tags: geometry, analysis, derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the equation

$$0.26639x-0.043941y+(5.9313\times10^{-5})xy-(3.9303\times{10^{-6}}) y^2-7242.0404=0$$

with $x,y>0$. If you plot it, it'll look like below:

[image]

Now, I want to find a minimum point on this hyperbola, such that $x+y$ is a minimum. 
In other words:
$$\min(x+y)$$
$$Constraints: $$
$$0.26639x-0.043941y+(5.9313\times10^{-5})xy-(3.9303\times{10^{-6}}) y^2-7242.0404=0$$

Any help on how to mathematically find this point would be really helpful.

I've asked [a similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276124/how-to-find-the-corner-point-of-a-non-function-equation), but in this one, I wanted to find a corner point such that the hyperbola has the maximum curvature. But this is not the case in this question.

Comment: Initial thought: you're investigating which line of the form $x+y=c,$ or $y=-x+c,$ touching the hyperbola in at least one point, minimizes $c.$ The problem is that most, if not all, hyperbolas will intersect such lines as $c\to-\infty.$ Therefore, I don't think you have enough constraints on the problem to find a sensible minimum. Now, if you were to minimize $|x+y|,$ that would be sufficiently constrained. Then you're asking which line of the form I've described has the $y$ intersept closest to the origin.

Comment: Wait, never mind: you have $x>0$ and $y>0.$ That will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Assuming the plot gives the restriction shape, the minimum is located in the first quadrant, at the tangency point between the restriction and the line $x+y=\lambda$. Now calling the restriction

$$
g(x,y) = a x + b y + c x y + d y^2 + e = 0
$$

making the substitution $y = \lambda-x$ we get

$$
a x+b (\lambda -x)+c x (\lambda -x)+d (\lambda -x)^2+e = 0\ \ \ (1)
$$

and after solving for $x$ we get

$$
x = \frac{2 d \lambda\pm \sqrt{(a-b+\lambda  (c-2 d))^2+4 (c-d) (\lambda  (b+d \lambda )+e)}-a+b-c
   \lambda }{2 (d-c)}
$$

but at tangency we have only one solution for $x$ so

$$
(a-b+\lambda  (c-2 d))^2+4 (c-d) (\lambda  (b+d \lambda )+e)=0
$$

for $\lambda = 18287.7$ and after substituting into $(1)$

$$
x = 12165.6
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Cesareo. I didn't get the step "but at tangency we have..."...Why you make it equal to zero?

Comment: At tangency we have only one value for $\lambda$ This implies on the condition for null discriminant.

Comment: I think the value of x that you calculated should be 5884.34 http://bit.ly/2LAJIgx

Comment: @linker Thanks. I had really confused the formulas. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do you think we should take a similar approach for solving $$g(x,y) = a x + b y + c x y + d y^2 + e + l x^2 = 0$$, which is the general form of my problem?

Comment: @linker Yes. It works for any not degenerated conic.

Answer (score 2):

Our goal, as I mentioned in my first comment, is to find the line of the form $y=-x+c$ that minimizes $c,$ and which intersects your hyperbola in the first quadrant.

1. Find $y'(x).$ I'm actually going to view $x=x(y)$ and find $dx/dy.$ Note that if $dy/dx=-1,$ then $dx/dy=-1$ as well. Moreover, in the other post, I found $x(y)$ explicitly. We have:
   \begin{align*}
   x(y)&=\frac{7242.0404+\left(3.9303\times{10^{-6}}\right) y^2+0.043941y}{0.26639+\left(5.9313\times10^{-5}\right)\!y} \\
   x'(y)&=\frac{0.0662637 y^2+595.215 y-1.18771\times 10^8}{(1. y+4491.26)^2}
   \end{align*}
2. Set $x'(y)=-1.$ We have 
   $x'(y)=-1 \implies y=6122.12, \; x=12165.6.$
   This solution is in the first quadrant, so we see that there is a point satisfying our needs. Note: this was also my first approach in the previous problem, but it didn't give quite as good a result for that problem.
3. Now, we only need find the $c$ that serves as the $y$ intersept, and that will be the minimum. We have
   \begin{align*}
   y&=-x+c \\
   6122.12&=-12165.6+c \\
   18287.7&=c.
   \end{align*}
   So that's the minimum, and it occurs at $(12165.6, 6122.12).$

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian for your comment. What if we won’t be able to write the equation in a form of a function (as x(y)). Or what if its not a hyperbola? How can we find y’(x) ? Or in general, solve this problem?

Comment: I think more generally, as long as you're minimizing $x+y$ in a sufficiently constrained space like the first quadrant, this general approach could still work. Now, you might not have a solution to $y'(x)=-1$ or $x'(y)=-1$ in the first quadrant. In that case, you could try substituting $y=-x+c$ into the equation you have, solving for $c,$ and then setting $c'(x)=0.$ There's no one way to solve these sorts of problems, which is why it pays to have a "bag of tricks" you can bring out for whatever problem you do have.

Comment: Even though your solution was so helpful and I genuinely appreciate your help, but Cesaro solution fitted to my problem perfectly.

Comment: @linker: Hey, no need to apologize! Cesareo's solution is perfectly adequate, and it would be the height of arrogance to think that the way I approach or explain a solution is always the best fit for someone else.